# Only allow users to access an external page from Wordpress (redirect the rest to the wordpress website) - HTACCESS

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, referrer

I have a html5 webpage within my domain, that I only want to be accessable when referred to from a Wordpress website, which I host in another subdirectory in my domain. Once accessed directly the user will be reffered to the Wordpress page. This works. However if the webpage is accessed from the link in my Wordpress page, the result is the same Wordpress page opens in a new browser tab instead of the external webpage referred to.
I'm using Wordpress 5.7.1 and a .htaccess file in the directory of the html5 webpage. It contains the following code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://mydomain.nl [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.mydomain.nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain/wordpresspage [L,R]
```

If I do the same from a Classicpress page or another cms it works fine, so I guess there is something in Wordpress that makes it fail.
How can I get this working from within Wordpress aswell?

Thanks in advance for helping me.
Erik

Answer (score 0):

So the simple solution for this thing is that you can use the javascript's DOM referrer Property. In this, you can specify that if the user is coming from that WordPress website then you can give them access, or else you can redirect them to their previous page

Learn About that Property here:- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp

and for this, you will also have to use if...else property as well with it. From this idea, you can create your own code for it!!

Example:-
You can create a middle page for it ,that is, a new page with some name and put the following script code in it which will redirect the user to the HTML5 page if it is coming from that WordPress website / page and if it is coming from another page, the user will be redirected to the previous page

The code is :-

```html
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.referrer;
    var y = "http://yourwordpressurl.com/"
    if (x==y) {
    window.location.href = "https://yourhtml5pagewebsite.com"
} else {
  window.location.href = x
}
}
</script>
```

Thanks.